# Getting Python output in real-time from C++/boost::process

Tags: python, c++, boost-process

From a C++ program (running under Windows 10), I use boost::process to invoke Python in order to interpret a simple Python script. I want to redirect Python script's output in real-time to my C++ program's console.

My problem is that I'm getting the whole Python script output at once when the program completed, I'm not getting it in real-time.

Here is my MCVE:

**Python script (script.py):**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

print( "Started Python script at t=" + str(datetime.now().time()) )

time.sleep(1)
print( "Slept 1 sec, t=" + str(datetime.now().time()) )
time.sleep(1)
print( "Slept 1 sec, t=" + str(datetime.now().time()) )

print( "Stopped Python script at t=" + str(datetime.now().time()) )
```

**C++ program (main.cpp):**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

namespace bp = boost::process;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& time_point) 
{
    const auto time {std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t (time_point)};
    const auto localtime {*std::localtime (&time)};
    const auto time_since_epoch {time_point.time_since_epoch()};
    const auto milliseconds_count {std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (time_since_epoch).count() % 1000};
    
    stream << "[" << std::put_time (&localtime, "%T") << "." << std::setw (3) << std::setfill ('0') << milliseconds_count << "] - ";
    return stream;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << "Creating child" << std::endl;
    bp::ipstream stream;
    bp::child c("python.exe", "script.py", bp::std_out > stream);
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << "Created child" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << "Invoking getline" << std::endl;
    std::string line;
    while (getline(stream, line)) {
        std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << "From Python output: " << line << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << "getline ended" << std::endl;

    c.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs:

> [12:50:34.684] - Creating child
> [12:50:34.706] - Created child
> [12:50:34.708] - Invoking getline
> [12:50:36.743] - From Python output: Started Python script at t=12:50:34.742105
> [12:50:36.745] - From Python output: Slept 1 sec, t=12:50:35.743111
> [12:50:36.745] - From Python output: Slept 1 sec, t=12:50:36.743328
> [12:50:36.746] - From Python output: Stopped Python script at t=12:50:36.743328
> [12:50:36.747] - getline ended

As you can see, we get the whole 4 outputs after Python process ended (first call to `getline` freezes for 2 seconds - while Python runs the two `time.sleep(1)` - and then within 3ms we get the whole 4 lines). I would expect to get something like:

> [12:50:34.684] - Creating child
> [12:50:34.706] - Created child
> [12:50:34.708] - Invoking getline
> [12:50:3**4.XXX**] - From Python output: Started Python script at t=12:50:34.742105
> [12:50:3**5.XXX**] - From Python output: Slept 1 sec, t=12:50:35.743111
> [12:50:36.XXX] - From Python output: Slept 1 sec, t=12:50:36.743328
> [12:50:36.XXX] - From Python output: Stopped Python script at t=12:50:36.743328
> [12:50:36.XXX] - getline ended

I suspect the problem comes more from `boost::process` than from Python, but all the examples I could find for `boost::process` are reading `std::cout` the same way. Is there any thing I should change to have the `getline` loop run in real-time while Python prints output?

Comment: In python code you have to do `print('SOME_THING', flush = True)`, i.e. add `flush = True` to every `print`. And in C++ code you have to add `std::cout << "SOME_THING" << std::flush;`, i.e. add `std::flush` to `cout` at every printing. Also C++ probably flushes at `std::endl` output, but that is not guaranteed, so better to output `std::flush` everywhere too. Python doesn't flush at end-line at all, just from time to time. After these two changes to Python and C++ code outputs of both programs will be synchronized.

Comment: @Arty: True, that's what I did considering Basile's answer. And you are right, Python does not flush on EOL, only some time to time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python streams are (like C streams or C++ ones) buffered (for performance reasons).

You may want to use some [`flush` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) in your Python code.

And your question could be operating system specific. For Linux, be also aware of [fsync(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) and [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) (and [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) and [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)...). For other operating systems, read their documentation.

Comment: Hello Basile, thank you for your help. I thougth that as `print` was adding EOL, that would automatically flush (as it does in C/C++). But you are right, adding some `sys.stdout.flush()` in Python script OR adding `-u` option while invoking Python (`-u` means "force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered") fix the issue